# NodeJS - Passing data to the httpRequest made

Tags: node.js, express, sockets

I have a router as below in a node express server,

Router1:

```
  router.post('/generatebuild', (req, res, next)=> {
      // I am doing operation to generate build and compressing it to a zip.
      // There are many messages consoled here for tracing.
      console.log("BUILD URL:<url>")
      res.download(zip);
  });
```

Now I am sending a request to the above from another node server,

Router2:

```
  router.post('/deploy', (req, res, next) => {
     http.request("http://localhost:8000/generatebuild", function (res) {
         const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream("./temp.zip");
         res.on('data', (chunk) => {
             writeStream.write(chunk);
         });
         //I need some idea to print the consoled statements which are available in `generatebuild` request to be printed here.
     }, {
         method: 'POST'
     });
 });
```

Both the above routers are on different node servers. Downloading zip works fine but I would like to pass the consoled statements from the requested URL.( I would like to exchange messages ). Could you please guide me to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

One Way To Solve This Use Common Database Where You Can Write Consoled Message Of "/generatebuild" To Database And Read Them From Database at "/deploy" after getting response.

Comment: Is it possible to send both the zip and the log file as formdata?